# Passing PHP Array to JavaScript Function Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, onclick

I am trying to pass a php array to The JavaScript Function `FindCheckBoxes(Test)` using `onClick` functionality. But this code does not seem to work. It Seems like `JSON_ENCODING` is not working.

How do I pass my $array variable to the JavaScript Function. I have searched the internet but can't get it to work. That is, alert spits out nothing(a blank). I want '$array' parameters to be there
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  -->
        <title>Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Facebook Timeline" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
    $array =array(); 
    array_push($array,"aa");
    ?>
 function comment(){
     var jFirst = document.getElementById("usernamesignup").value;
    alert("Your name is: "+ jFirst);
 }
  function findCheckedBoxes(test) {
  alert("here");
            var select_array= new Array();
alert(test);            
           var AllBoxes = $(".pp");
           for(i=0;i<AllBoxes.length;i++)
           {
               if(AllBoxes[i].checked)
               {

                   select_array.push(foo[i]);
               }
               }
               alert(select_array);
               return true;
       }
 </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
 //PostID = 0 means its not a constraint 
 function comment($pauthor, $author, $substr, $start, $postid, $end) { 
     $q = "select * from Comment where Author like '".$author."%' and Text like '%".$substr."%' and Time >= '".$start."' and Time <= '".$end."' and (PostID = ".strval($postid)." or ".strval($postid)." = 0) and PostID in (select PostID from Post where Author like '".$pauthor."%')"; 

  return $q; 

 } 

 function user($user, $pre, $post, $sepr) { 
    if($user == 1) return $pre."1".$post.$sepr.$pre."2".$post.$sepr.$pre."3".$post; 
    if($user == 2) return $pre."2".$post.$sepr.$pre."3".$post; 
    //if($user == 3)  
    return $pre."3".$post; 
 } 

 function comb($q1, $q2, $q3) { 
    $str = "'000'"; 
    for($i = $q1; $i <= 3; $i++) { 
        for($j = $q2; $j <= 3; $j++) { 
            for($k = $q3; $k <= 3; $k++) { 
                $str = $str.", '".strval($i).strval($j).strval($k)."'"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $str; 
 } 

 function perm($g1, $g2, $g3,$union,$user) { 
    if($union) { 
        if($g1 && $g2 && $g3) //return "Permission_bits like %3% or Permission_bits like %2% or Permission_bits like %1%"; 
                                                    return    user($user, "Permission_bits like '%", "%'", " or "); 
        if($g1 && $g2) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '", "__'", " or ").user($user, "Permission_bits like '_", "_'", " or "); 
        if($g2 && $g3) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '__", "'", " or ").user($user, "Permission_bits like '_", "_'", " or "); 
        if($g1 && $g3) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '", "__'", " or ").user($user, "Permission_bits like '__", "'", " or "); 
        if($g1) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '", "__'", " or "); 
        if($g2) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '_", "_'", " or "); 
        if($g3) return user($user, "Permission_bits like '__", "'", " or "); 
        return "Permission_bits = '000'"; 
    } else { 
        if($g1 && $g2 && $g3) return    "Permission_bits in (".comb($user, $user, $user).")"; 
        if($g1 && $g2) return "Permission_bits in (".comb($user, $user, 0).")"; 
        if($g2 && $g3) return "Permission_bits in (".comb(0, $user, $user).")"; 
        if($g1 && $g3) return "Permission_bits in (".comb($user, 0, $user).")"; 
        if($g1) return "Permission_bits in (".comb($user, 0, 0).")"; 
        if($g2) return "Permission_bits in (".comb(0, $user, 0).")"; 
        if($g3) return "Permission_bits in (".comb(0, 0, $user).")"; 
        return "Permission_bits = '000'"; 
    } 
 } 
 ?> 
<?php
$author=$_REQUEST['author'];
$pauthor=$_REQUEST['post_author'];
$text=$_REQUEST['text'];
$start=$_REQUEST['start'];
$end=$_REQUEST['end'];
?>



        <div class="container">
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">

                <span class="right">

                </span>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header>
                <h1>FACEBOOK TIMELINE</h1>

            </header>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form action="comments.php" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1>COMMENTS</h1> 
                                <br>
                                <br>

                                <TABLE>
                                <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
                                <td>
<img src="comments.jpg" align="center" width=400>   

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</td>



                                <td>

<FORM id="FORM"  action="comments.php" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="1" VALUE="START A NEW SEARCH HERE " >
</FORM>
                            </td>
                                </TABLE>
                                                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH=200px ALIGN=CENTER>
<tr>
<h1>YOUR RESULTS</h1>
<INPUT  TYPE="button"  onClick="findCheckedBoxes('<?php  json_encode($array); ?>')" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO GROUP MEMBERS ONLY" />
<INPUT  TYPE="button"  onclick="findCheckedBoxes()" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO YOUR FRIENDS ONLY"/>
<INPUT  TYPE="button"  onclick="findCheckedBoxes()" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO EVERYBODY" />
<?php 
//echo '<FORM id="MYFORM0"  onsubmit="return findCheckedBoxes()" >

//</FORM>.<br>.<br>';
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("10.142.233.33", "root", "limiwisn") or die(mysql_error()); 
  //mysql_connect("", "root", "guitar") or die(mysql_error()); 
$count=0;
 mysql_select_db("Ass3") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $datai = mysql_query(comment($pauthor, $author, $text, $start, 0, $end))
  or die(mysql_error());
 while($infoi = mysql_fetch_array( $datai )) 
 {
$count = $count + 1;
 }  
 echo '<tr><td><font size=5>';
 echo "Total number of Comments ->".strval($count)."<br><br>";
 echo '</tr></td></font>';
 echo "<br>";
 mysql_select_db("Ass3") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $datai = mysql_query(comment($pauthor, $author, $text, $start, 0, $end))
  or die(mysql_error());
 echo '<tr><td><font size=4>';

 while($infoi = mysql_fetch_array( $datai )) 
 {
  echo $infoi['CommentID']."<br>";
  echo '<input type="checkbox" class="pp" name="sdfsdg" value="my_checkbox"/>'.'<br>';
  echo $infoi['Author']."<br>";
  echo $infoi['Text']."<br>";
  echo $infoi['Time']."<br><br><br>"; 
  array_push($array,$infoi['CommentID']);
 }  
  echo "<br>";
  echo '</td></tr></font>';
echo '</table>'; 
print_r ($array);
 ?>
                                <br>
                                <br>





                            </form>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is far too long. Reduce it to the bare necessities!

Comment: So, what does "But this code does not seem to work" mean?  What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?  Are you seeing JS errors in the error console? What does your `alert(test);` spit out? What do you expect it to spit out?

Comment: I am sorry but i have edited it now. Kindly have a look

Comment: So when you look at the HTML source, what is contained in the the `findCheckBoxes` function call (inside the input's onClick attribute)?

Comment: @Steve i din't get u. I want to pass the $array using onClick(that i get from php after modification ). But the Alert pops up an empty array

Comment: What I meant was:  When you load the page, look at the HTML that gets sent to the browser (right click and select "View Source", or use Firebug, or equivalent). When you look at the HTML, copy and paste the line after `<h1>YOUR RESULTS</h1>` into here and show us what you've got.

Comment: <INPUT  TYPE="button"  onClick="findCheckedBoxes('')" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO GROUP MEMBERS ONLY" />
<INPUT  TYPE="button"  onclick="findCheckedBoxes()" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO YOUR FRIENDS ONLY"/>
<INPUT  TYPE="button"  onclick="findCheckedBoxes()" VALUE="CHANGE PERMISSION TO EVERYBODY" />

Comment: @Steve Is there any problem with onClick="findCheckedBoxes('')" . I want to get $array . But this parameter seems to be empty

Comment: That just means that your `$array` value is empty... so you first need to figure out what's going on on the PHP side with  that variable.

Comment: @Steve when i print the array after computing in php i get a set of values implying that it is not empty. The error is somewhere else ....

Comment: In your example, you print the array WAY after you use it in the input field.

Comment: @Steve I see the problem now. The value that is passed now is ["aa"] . This implies that the updation from the database is taking place after the parameter is sent. How is this possible? What is the way around to send the parameter after the database updation?

Comment: @Steve can u please tell me that if my encoding that is sent is something like ["aa","bb","cc"], how to I convert it to a javascript array in the function after receiving it as parameter

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` simply returns the value - you still need to tell php what to do with it, ie. replace this:

`<?php  json_encode($array); ?>`

with this:

`<?php  echo json_encode($array); ?>`

Possible case of staring at the screen too long?

Answer (score 0):

you must first eval the json code. the parameter that you have passed to function is in string format.
first test to remove the quotes if not work test `eval('<?php  json_encode($array); ?>')` or `eval( '(' + '<?php  json_encode($array); ?>' + ')' )`

Comment: If you wanted to evaluate it in-line why would you choose `eval` over `jsonp`?